Unable to load dynamic library because php_sqlite.dll canot be found
I use windows 7 and XAMPP V 3.2.1
For some reasons, I need to move my old data in old PC in XAMPP to New PC.
So I download the exact XAMPP to New PC and move all the database , structure to the new Computer.
Long story short, all the data migration is completed and I can open the program like usual.
However, every time I try to start running "Apache" in Xampp it shows

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlite.dll"-The specified module could not be found.

when I click "ok" it will disapear and so far, didn't effect the program.
Anyone can help how to repair this error?
Regards,
I tried to changing the "extension=php_sqlite.dll" into "extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll"' in php.ini.
result

Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded



Open php.ini and comment out or remove extension=php_sqlite.dll if not needed.
Ensure extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll is enabled (remove the semicolon ; if necessary).
Restart Apache in XAMPP.

This should resolve the issue.

You can use php -m to find out the "Show compiled in modules"
For compiled in modules, there is no need to add them using the extension= in your PHP.INI.
For more info see: how to find the version numbers of built in modules in php from the CLI

Either write ; before the line, as
;extension=php_sqlite.dll

to deactivate sqlite, or, if you need it, install this PHP module on your computer. Or, if you need it, then install SQLite3 as well as PHP support for it, as it can be seen here.
